# .NET WebRequest to CloudFlare causes SSL exception after 1 hour idle period

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, httpwebrequest, cloudflare

I've been having issues with a tool I use to upload images to a website behind CloudFlare. This tool works fine at first, and continues functioning unless there is a > 1 hour pause between requests. After this pause, an exception occurs on the next connection attempt.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

I attempted to use a debugger to poke into this deeper, but there was no InnerException and it seems the actual issue originated from SChannel before any connection was established. This is readily replicable using the following small program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initial connection attempt, this should succeed:");
        RunCFRequest();
        Console.WriteLine("Wait 70 minutes for next connection attempt...");
        Thread.Sleep(70*60*1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Second connection attempt, this one should reproduce the failure:");
        try
        {
            RunCFRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Performing another connection attempt after failure to verify we continue working:");
        RunCFRequest();
        Console.WriteLine("Demo complete. Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void RunCFRequest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting connection at " + DateTime.Now);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://up1.ca");
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string recvd = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully read stream, got " + recvd.Length + " bytes of data");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with this simple code? I attempted to do packet capture in order to resolve why this is occurring.

Capture is available at https://up1.ca/#4MMkdD_u8v5pLAsSvrCtHw in pcapng format.

The capture contains 3 TCP streams, they can be accessed using the following wireshark filters:

- tcp.stream eq 0 = inital connection, succeeds
- tcp.stream eq 1 = second connection after 70 minutes, this fails with the above exception
- tcp.stream eq 2 = another attempt after handling and ignoring that exception, this succeeds

Based on the capture my best guess is that it has something to do with how CloudFlare does SSL session resumption. Are there any known problems with HttpWebRequest or Microsoft SChannel itself and SSL resumption or is this issue specific to CloudFlare? I've successfully replicated this problem on multiple sites behind CloudFlare, but I have not experienced it when using my own server directly. I don't have SSL resumption though.

Any help or even wild theories are appreciated. I'm not sure where to go from here, I'd appreciate it if someone could have a look at the capture, I'll report this to CF if needed.

Comment: You have not disposed of any resources. Wrap everything in using blocks, update the code here and rerun the test. Let's make sure this is not the reason for the problems.

Comment: @usr Sure, though I believe the code for the full out application does so. I'll update in 70 minutes or so when the test completes.

Comment: @usr I've updated the existing code with the usings, would you mind verifying that these are correct? Thank you.

Comment: Code looks fine. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2005/01/02/345411.aspx and classes mentioned in the article (in particular lease related) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380250/close-all-underlying-network-connections for leads - basically stopping connection reuse - I guess it should force re-creating SSL connection instead of trying to continue using the same one.

Comment: Seems completely correct now. Also post the full exception ToString (you can capture it with the debugger if necessary). The call stack might give clues.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think it's a connection reuse issue, but an SSL session reuse issue (reuses cryptographic contexts and such). The connection appears to close in the capture, long before the second connection even starts.

Comment: @usr Issue was duplicated successfully with the disposal occuring.
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at CFProblemDemo.Program.RunCFRequest() in c:\Users\ultra\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 35
   at CFProblemDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\ultra\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 19

see https://up1.ca/#EsrcuTAFhSS5uFcwsBWCjQ for line numbers if you want

Comment: To add to that, as I mentioned in the original post, there's no further details in the exception except for it originating from SChannel (with no further details listed there and no InnerException or anything).

Comment: You can set the debugger to break on all exceptions. Maybe there is an internal exception that was handled. Small chance to find something out. Contact the CDN and explain the issue. Maybe you can use WireShark to look into the TLS session. As a work around maybe you can clear the SChannel state, I have no idea. http://serverfault.com/questions/529304/how-do-i-clear-cached-ssl-state-data-from-schannel

Comment: I did the break on all exceptions method, however, as I mentioned it had no InnerException and didn't seem to have any further useful information, short of that it was coming from SChannel. I've also got a packet capture from wireshark posted in the top too, didn't seem to help me much. On the failing connection, it appears my machine sends a RST to cloudflare after getting the Server Hello (possibly didn't like that it got a new session id when it had used an existing one,just speculation though) Clearing the SChannel state is an interesting idea, I'll probably take this up with CF though

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue connecting to the Fitbit API which just turned on CloudFlare. Please upvote this .NET Framework issue. Seems to be a bug in the HttpWebRequest class sending expired hourly keys: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb999cd4-b43b-4779-b01b-4a04017714e3/httpwebrequest-ssl-caching-bug-cloudflare-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssltls?forum=netfxbcl